# How to speed up routeParams process in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a data list of about 12,000 items.
to view data of individual items from the 12,000, I use routeparams and fetch data using itemId.

But doing so takes a lot of time to load data. Is there any method to speed up the process?
Thank you

Comment: What database are you using? A few more details would be helpful

Comment: I'm pretty sure that has nothing to do with $routeParams, I think the problem is the time it takes you to fetch the data from your back-end API.

Comment: I am using MYSQL, and yes using php i have exported a json file, through which the data is accessed.

Comment: Set up an index on your database.

Comment: You should try checking the time your back-end takes to get the data and export it, that should be less than 1 second unless there's something really wrong with your mysql server / query. 12k rows is a really small amount of data for mysql. You can also have a look in the developer console of your browser to see how much time the request takes.